# Ruby issue: My "gets" function executes before my "puts" statement

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby and I tried a simple code:

```
system "clear"
print "What is your name?"
name = gets.chomp
puts name
puts "Hello #{ name.capitalize }, how are you?"
```

and the oupout is ready for the input without showing the print requested. then after I enter a string it show the print:

```
George
What is your name?George
Hello George, how are you?
```

Please help. I am confused. Thank you!

Comment: You call `gets` before you call `puts`, so the `gets` *should* be executed before the `puts`. What is the issue with that?

Comment: How do you run that code?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the "print" instead of "puts". I want "print" to come before "gets".

Answer (score 4):

This is likely caused by output buffering and should be fixed by adding `$stdout.sync = true` before the first `print` statement.

Another solution is to call `$stdout.flush` to manually flush output after the `print` statement or replace `print` with `puts` (but that will add a newline).

Comment: That shouldn't be needed. Ruby automatically flushes the output if stdout is a tty. (adding `$stdout.sync` will probably solve the issue nonetheless)

Comment: TDOUT.sync = true Solved it. Interesting finding. Thank you all.

Comment: @Stefan There are likely subtle differences between platforms, especially Windows vs Unix, see https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/immediately-print-a-string-on-stdout-without-new-line/143169/7

Comment: @Stefan I just tested the example from the above post with Ruby 1.8.7 on macOS 10.15.4 and it uses buffering until a newline is printed, while on Ruby 2.7.0 is prints immediately, so maybe the OP is using a very old Ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied OP's code into my editor (VS Code) and I don't get what OP got. 
I got

```
What is your name?George
George
Hello George, how are you?
```

instead of

```
George
What is your name?George
Hello George, how are you?
```